# Diff between two directories and keep only the unchanged ones

Tags: macos, bash, diff

I need to diff two directories:

```
 A: /path1/
 B: /path2/
```

1. The directory A contains all files and subdirectories that are also contained in B.
2. The files in A (and in its subdirectories) can have different contents of the equivalent files in B.
3. The directory A (and its subdirectories) also has extra files that do not exist in B.

What I would like to achieve is:

- Keep only the files in A that differ from the files in B plus all the extra files that don't exist in B.
- Delete all the other files in A that do not respect the previous rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This approach should work:

```
cd /path1

find . -type f -exec cmp -s {} /path2/{} \; -delete
```

How it works:

- `find . -type f` goes through all files in the current directory (*A*) and its subdirectories.
- `cmp -s {} /path2/{}` silently (`-s`) compares the currently processed file (`{}`) to the matching file in *B* (`/path2/{}`).
- If the files are identical, cmp returns true and the `-exec` condition matches.
- If the `-exec` condition matches, `-delete` deletes the file.

I suggest replacing `-delete` with `-print` before running the actual command to verify if it works as expected.

---

To deal with leftover empty directories, you can execute the command:

```
find . -type d -exec rmdir -p {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

- `-type d` only finds directories.
- `-exec rmdir -p {} \;` executes `rmdir -p {}` for every directory that has been found.

  `{}` is the directory that has been found, and the `-p` switch makes rmdir remove its empty parent directories as well.
- `2> /dev/null` suppresses the error messages that will arise from trying to delete non-empty or previously deleted directories.

Since rmdir cannot delete non-empty directories, this should be the safest way.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am on Mac Os X and I've just found out that many `find` options are different or are not implemented at all. I'll try to translate your command for the Mac implementation of `find`. Any tip would be welcome as well.

Comment: According to [find(1) OS X Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html), neither `-exec` nor `-delete` are GNU extensions. I don't have OS X (so I can't test it), but my `find` command should work out of the box.

Comment: I solved installing the GNU `find` through brew: `brew install findutils`. It will create a bin called `gfind` that can be called instead of `find` or it can be aliased as `find`. Your script leaves the empty folders in place tough, any way to delete them? Thanks

Comment: I still don't know why it won't work with Mac OS X's find, but GNU find is much more powerful, so you haven't installed it in vain. I've edited my answer to add a solution for the empty directories. The approach assumes that `rmdir` cannot delete non-empty directories. As far as I know, that's true on Mac OS X a well.

Comment: I finally found out what the problem was. GNU find automatically processes the current directory (`.`) if none is specified. BSD find doesn't do this, so you have to execute `find . -type f ...`.