# How to set old modification times between the working directory and its backup recursively?

Tags: bash, time, date-time, timestamp, touch

Let's assume you have two directories, e.g., `/long_path_1` and `/long_path_2` (potentially with spaces), that you know to be almost equal, e.g., because you previously ran `diff -rq --no-dereferences /long_path_1 /long_path_2` and found out only minor differences (to give a concrete example, `.cache` and a few other dot-files are present in `$HOME` but not in `/mnt/username`, if these happen to be the directories you compare). You also know that certain modification times differ of many same–full-path, same-contents files and directories somewhere in the directory structure differ (e.g., because many years ago you were a bit careless and transferred the contents not via `cp -auv` but via `cp` or unpacked some files from archives without telling the archiver to set the file times properly or because the files were transferred between different file systems or via `scp` and the high precision got lost).  Out of two same–full-path, same-contents files, the file with the oldest time may lie on either side; it can lie either undernearth `/long_path_1/` or underneath `/long_path_1/`; you don't know.

If you had to do the task non-recursively, you'd run something like

```
diff -q --no-dereference "/long_path_1/some subdirectories/file or directory" "/long_path_2/some subdirectories/file or directory"
```

to make sure that the files are really equal, and if they are, look at the output of

```
ls -la --full-time "/long_path_1/some subdirectories/file or directory" "/long_path_2/some subdirectories/file or directory"
```

then manually compare the times and then issue either of

```
touch -r "/long_path_1/some subdirectories/file or directory" "/long_path_2/some subdirectories/file or directory"
```

(if the first dude is older) or

```
touch -r "/long_path_2/some subdirectories/file or directory" "/long_path_1/some subdirectories/file or directory"
```

(if the second dude is older)

How to do this recursively such that you get the oldest known modification times in both copies and not just in one? I consider something like

```
cd "/long_path_1"
find . -type f -exec bash -c "if [[ -f \"{}\" && -f \"/long_path_2/{}\" ]]; then if ( cmp -s \"{}\" \"/long_path_2/{}\" ) then if [[ \"{}\" -ot \"/long_path_2/{}\" ]]; then touch -r \"{}\" \"/long_path_2/{}\"; else if [[ \"/long_path_2/{}\" -ot \"{}\" ]]; then touch -r \"/long_path_2/{}\" \"{}\"; fi; fi; fi; fi" \;
find . -type l -exec bash -c "if [[ -h \"{}\" && -h \"/long_path_2/{}\" ]]; then if (test $(readlink \"{}\") = $(readlink \"/long_path_2/{}\")) then if (find \"/long_path_2/{}\" -prune -newer \"{}\" -printf 'a\n' | grep -q a) then touch -h -r \"{}\" \"/long_path_2/{}\"; else if (find \"{}\" -prune -newer \"/long_path_2/{}\" -printf 'a\n' | grep -q a) then touch -h -r \"/long_path_2/{}\" \"{}\"; fi; fi; fi; fi" \;
find . -type d -exec bash -c "if [[ -d \"{}\" && -d \"/long_path_2/{}\" ]]; then if (cmp -s <(ls -Al --full-time \"{}\") <(ls -Al --full-time \"/long_path_2/{}\") then if [[ \"{}\" -ot \"/long_path_2/{}\" ]]; then touch -r \"{}\" \"/long_path_2/{}\"; else if [[ \"/long_path_2/{}\" -ot \"{}\" ]]; then touch -r \"/long_path_2/{}\" \"{}\"; fi; fi; fi; fi" \;
```

but it's really cumbersome (because it runs though the directory structure thrice and spawns a bash for every file), and I have no idea how to do the right thing, especially for symlinks, directories (how to compare them?), and symlinks to directories.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777606/edit) the question to add the script you currently use to achieve the purpose, and explanation on how the script fails, i.e. what exactly happens when you run it.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I don't have any script as of now. I can look up single simple commands and execute them from bash with simple options but simply don't know enough to write such a script.

Comment: Ah. In that case you're out of luck. SU isn't a free scripting service. If you have a script which doesn't work as you'd expect, you can post your script here for review / analysis, and you will get help on fixing it. However nobody will write one for you from scratch.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I understand. However, there might already be a tool for this (a reference would suffice) or someone might have already written such a script. The {uni|linu}x world is old, and the task should be pretty common. Perhaps, a kind of diff with an exec option for each match could be a start, if it exists.

Comment: Yes, but still not happening, this isn't a place where scripts are swapped. You need to do the work first. You can easily find any number of free, good quality scripting tutorials and other resources all over the internet. I'd suggest checking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour), Asking and Answering in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) and some older questions with [accepted answers](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) to get a grasp on how SuperUser works.

Comment: @Peregrino69 If you put it into your mind that necessarily a script is asked for, then you are wrong, my friend. Do me a favor and reread the question; the word “script” is even not mentioned. Though a script could be a solution, it doesn't have to be. And you are wrong twice because the scripts ARE swapped here. An example is a two-liner from https://superuser.com/a/561207; it is a script (or a program, in other words), albeit a simple one.

Comment: That question is from 2013 ...

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a one-off to fix existing file times, then `rsync -rct` will make it a lot simpler (`r`ecursively compare only file `c`hecksum, and update `t`ime stamps from source if different).

You still have to say which source folder is the "older" one to copy times from. Try with `rsync -vvrctn /src /dst` to have it only dump a list of files whose timestamps differ so you can review.

---

That final step of "only older files" is many orders of magnitude more difficult to handle in bash, and (as you've found) timestamps aren't really trustworthy enough for most backup/restore purposes. If you expect to need to regularly roll back+sync files, then you might want to look into source/version control tools.

Comment: You know that, even though the likelyhood of silent errors is small, comparing the ckecksums to test data equality is simply wrong. I don't need yet another source of errors in addition to hardware glitches (which do occur). Thus, I'm willing to let the files or their meta data be compared bytewise. As for the list of files, it can be huge (e.g., in case of comparing `$HOME` vs. its backup `/mnt/username`.) and not processable manually without error. In bash, is comparing high-precision timestamps difficult or which part of "transfer timestamps from older files" is difficult?

Comment: Anyway, thank you; I'm going to test and report here as soon as I can.

Comment: @AlMa0 rsync does have `--size-only` for bytesize comparisons instead of `-c`hecksum. Comparing times in bash requires 1) listing relative file paths, bytes, and timestamps, 2) *accurately* splitting out each field, 3) comparing the paths, bytes, and timestamps + keeping the older one, then 4) updating the timestamp. It's not impossible, but is prone to issues with handling weird filenames/symlinks/etc, and such. If you can handle getting recursive lists of the files in a usable format, then unix.stackexchange.com may be able to help with processing comparisons

Comment: I've just discovered `if [[ FILE1 -ot FILE2 ]]; then echo "FILE1 is older than FILE2"; fi`, which does what it says assuming both files exist.

Comment: I updated the question. What do you think?

Comment: @AlMa0 you're on the right track. It could be more efficient to do `find . -type f > files.txt` first, then loop through the file paths in a single bash rather than spawning new ones, a la https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash. Whatever you end up using, test out whether it handles filenames with wildcard/quote characters/etc if needed.

Comment: If you want to keep the same behavior as `diff --no-dereference` for symlinks, just ignore them (`find -f` already does this). You'll be comparing the base files anyways